# Uploading and saving images in different resolutions on server

Tags: java, javascript, image, spring, jakarta-ee

I am developing a website using Java and Spring MVC. There is a form which allows entering some details and attaching images.  Both data and images get uploaded to the server when user submits the form (clicks submit button). The images uploaded are shown to user in three different sizes in three different places.

What I'm currently doing is resizing the images into three different resolutions and saving. But this makes the uploading slow as resizing adds to the processing time.

One way to speed things would be to run two parallel threads to do conversion and saving.

Is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three ways of doing this:

1. Synchronous, single-threaded.

   This is your current solution. Resizing images is performed sequentially (one by one) in the the same thread which handles the upload request, thus adding to the total request processing time (as you noticed, making the overall process noticeably slow). It's arguably the least complicated to implement. The control is returned back to user only after all images are processed (this is the "synchronous" part).
2. Synchronous, parallelised.

   Resizing images can likely benefit from parallelising, so you could use a `CompletionService` to submit all the resizing tasks and set them off to be processed concurrently and wait for all the tasks to complete (i.e. ) before sending back the response. User still has to wait until all images are ready.
3. Asynchronous.

   The upload handling controller would queue the resizing tasks to a service and return immediately; the resizing service would then do its best to process the images as quickly as possible. The problem with this approach is that it creates a short window in which control is back with the user but thumbnails are not ready yet. A common way of handling this (YouTube, etc.) is to display some sort of a placeholder saying "still processing" until real results are ready.

You're the only one who can pick the best solution, depending on your requirements and how dynamic your page is supposed to be, for example can it poll the server to check if the resizing jobs have completed (and placeholders can be replaced with actual resized images)